# Having issues starting a service in a referenced library project

Tags: android, android-service

To share some code between projects I created a new eclipse project marking it as a library project, following google's directions[1].

Everything compiles fine, but when I run the app it silently dies when it is unable to find the service.  Logcat shows the following:

```
WARN/ActivityManager(52): Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.iis.agatha/com.iis.common.services.FenceSyncService }: not found
```

As per the instructions[1] I have the library services referenced within the main project's manifest file as well as the library project.  I have tried refactoring the library project namespace to com.iis.agatha to match that main project without any luck.

```
<!-- SERVICES: Main project -->
<service android:name="com.iis.common.services.GeoLocationService" />
<service android:name="com.iis.common.services.FenceSyncService" />

<!-- SERVICES: Library project -->
<service android:name="com.iis.common.services.GeoLocationService" />
<service android:name="com.iis.common.services.FenceSyncService" />
```

Any ideas?

1. http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html

Comment: Have you added the library project as a library to the app?

Comment: Yes, I have.  As mentioned the app compiles and all references to the library project don't cause any compilation errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some where when running into some other problems I foolishly moved the service xml tags up out of the `<application />` and into the `<manifest>`.  After moving them back all works fine.

Comment: Could you please post how you start the service from your activity/fragment?